# How to iterate through all rows in spreadsheet when we insert new rows inside a loop?

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I would like to ask how can we iterate through all rows in a spreadsheet when we inside the loop add new rows.

For example, I have 100 rows in a spreadsheet with data. I loop through them:

```
for row in self.worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, 
max_col=self.worksheet.max_column, max_row=self.worksheet.max_row):
    for cell in row:
    ...
```

And in the inner loop, I have some conditions under which I insert a new row.

So for example I insert about 10 new rows so now I have 110 rows but the loop iterate only for the first 100 rows.

I would like to include these new rows also into iteration.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I managed to solve my problem. I was inserting new rows to sorted data where I wanted to have a new row to separate each subgroup of sorted data.

The problem was that when I inserted a new row in a loop the number of rows changed but in the loop, there was a fixed number of rows. So remaining last subgroups of data were not separated by new rows.

I managed to solve that by in the main loop appending rows numbers to a list and in a new loop iterate through this list and inside it insert new rows to dynamically changed row numbers.

Here is this code:

```
    dynamic_row_id = 0
    flag_first = True
    for row_num in row_numbers_to_insert_list:
        if flag_first:
            self.worksheet.insert_rows(row_num)
            flag_first = False
        else:
            dynamic_row_id += 1
            row_num += dynamic_row_id
            self.worksheet.insert_rows(row_num)
```

When we for example have in list rows numbers [5,6,7,8,9] we have to add to this numbers 1 for each row inserted so we have 5+1, 6+2, 7+3, 8+4, and 9+5.

And that would be the solution to my problem. I hope it will help someone else too.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean check for existing rows in the excel file to avoid duplicate rows?

Comment: No @Aditya. I already posted the answer to my problem. Have a great day :-).